# Integration Dialogflow CX with Google Chat

Tags: dialogflow-cx, google-chat

I'm in a project to create a chatbot with Dialogflow CX and I have to integrate it with Google Chat. I couldn't find anything about it on the internet. Does anyone know if this is possible? Does anyone have any content links on this?

I'm in a project to create a chatbot with Dialogflow CX and I have to integrate it with Google Chat. I couldn't find anything about it on the internet. Does anyone know if this is possible? Does anyone have any content l

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to integrate a Dialogflow CX chatbot with Google Chat. There are two ways to do this:

- **Using the Dialogflow console:**

  1. Go to the Dialogflow CX Console.
  2. Click the **Integrations** tab.
  3. Click **Google Chat**.
  4. Select who can access the app.
  5. Click **Start**.
- **Using the Google Cloud console:**

  1. Go to the Google Cloud console.
  2. Click the **Navigation menu** (three horizontal lines) in the top left corner.
  3. Click **APIs & Services**.
  4. Click **Library**.
  5. Search for **Google Chat API**.
  6. Click **Enable**.
  7. Click the **Configuration** tab.
  8. Configure the app.
  9. In the **Visibility** pane, select who can access the app.
  10. Click **Publish**.

Once you have integrated your Dialogflow CX chatbot with Google Chat, you can add it to a Google Chat space and start interacting with it. To add the chatbot to a space, click the **Add people & apps** button in the top right corner of the space and select the chatbot.

Here are some content links on this topic:

- Dialogflow CX documentation on integration with Google Chat: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/google-chat
- Quickstart: Interactions with an integration: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/integration
- Video tutorial on integrating Dialogflow CX with Google Chat: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRswG2oowEA

I hope this helps!